# Design patterns to optimize JavaScript code for data table manipulation

Tags: javascript, jquery, oop, optimization

This following table should behave like so:

- Add line item from inputs in tfoot when clicking + glyph
- Add line item from inputs in tfoot when tabbing out of Qty (or Subtotal if made editable)
- Remove line item when clicking x glyph
- Calculate subtotal before adding line item
- Edit line item fields when clicked (Description turns to textarea)
- Tab through line item fields in "edit mode"
- Enforce uppercase input on column 1
- Enforce numeric only input values on columns 6,7,8
- Recalculate row subtotal when edit occurs in columns 6,7
- Calculate and populate Total on table load
- Convert table into hidden inputs for saving on backend

[image]

Most of the functionality already works, but as features were added the code started to become unruly (see Bootply here: http://bootply.com/107629). I attempted to refactor most of it into a module, but hit a snag with how to refactor the many selectors used to attach event listeners & handlers.

My question is how do I best structure the code to make it more self-explanatory, easier to read/maintain, and clean up my attempt to modularize it so as to use fewer selectors on DOM-ready? I already posted a question to Code Review https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/39774/refactor-jquery-code-to-use-fewer-selectors, but with this question I'm looking for more general "best practices" type of answer for object-oriented JavaScript. A sort-of skeleton to restructure my existing code into.

The best way I can think to do this is to attach a click event listener to the whole table and then figure out which column was clicked and perhaps use a configuration array for what to do in the case of each column. Then have all the event handlers in a module. Or, parse the table when it's loaded and turn it into a JavaScript object, manipulate it that way, then redraw the table any time something changes?

**What design patterns might I use to optimize data table manipulation JavaScript code?**

Comment: Seems like a perfect fit for an MVVM framework (like [AngularJS](http://angularjs.org/)).

Comment: [KnockoutJS](http://knockoutjs.com/) is also an option.

Comment: Didn't even think of a JS MVVM given the current situation! Unfortunately, the client is concerned that using a framework would make the application more difficult to maintain for someone not familiar with that framework.

Comment: I was told to avoid frameworks, so I am trying to find which combination of design patterns to implement.